# Vertx Validation not working after Quarkus 3 upgrade

Tags: java, quarkus, vert.x

I recently upgraded the Quarkus Version to 3 in my gradle application and did the required updates mentioned in the Quarkus Docs.
But after the update Vertx validators are not throwing schema exception if I pass some invalid value.

Anyone faced anything similar?
I using version 4.5.0 for vertx

I tried upgrading Vertx json schema version but that did not work

Comment: Can you show a minimal reproducer?